# Responsive webpage scrollbar issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have created a SPA, which is working fine, but not the responsive part of it. Here is the `plunker`: http://plnkr.co/edit/NPHsIoirRJA1pS7KNopn?p=preview. There are 2 issues here:

1. When working with original desktop size there is no problem and when try to change the size the scrollbar is not available and half of the page is not visible.
2. While selecting an option from slide bar, the required page is being displayed but the slide bar doesn't hide automatically.
   Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have

   ```
   .site-container {
     overflow: hidden;
   }
   ```

In styleSheet1.css line 77 . It hides the scrollbar. Remove/comment it and everything will be fine again.

2. In index.html file I found jQuery portion:

   ```
   $('#site-cache').click(function(e) {
     $('body').removeClass('with--sidebar');
   });
   ```

It suppose to close left bar, but I didn't find any "site-cache" id anywhere. So edit it or add another portion to close left bar on menu click:

```
$('nav.menu a').click(function(e) {
 $('body').removeClass('with--sidebar');
});
```

It should work

Comment: Got one more issue here. I have included a table in dashboard tab. But it is not working as responsive. Here is the modified plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/NPHsIoirRJA1pS7KNopn?p=preview . Please let me know the style to be added for the table. Hope you will help.

Comment: Actually tables are not really responsive ready. What you have now is the best choice for mobile. You could also consider css zoom: 0.7 (or whatever). You could even consider some jQuery plugin like this: https://github.com/filamentgroup/tablesaw

Comment: Hi.. I need to include three level submenus for the menus added in the plunkr(Dashboard,Tab1). Tried a lot but couldn't get a responsive dropdown menu with 3levels of submenus. Wud be grateful if u can help..